# Text Selection Controls deprecated, user contextMenuBuilder instead

Tags: flutter

I have implemented a custom text selection control to add an open maps button next to the default copy/paste/selectAll on the highlighted text like so:

```
class MapTextSelectionControls extends MaterialTextSelectionControls {
  // Padding between the toolbar and the anchor.
  static const double _toolbarContentDistanceBelow = 20.0;
  static const double _toolbarContentDistance = 8.0;

  MapTextSelectionControls();

  @override
  Widget buildToolbar(
      BuildContext context,
      Rect globalEditableRegion,
      double textLineHeight,
      Offset selectionMidpoint,
      List<TextSelectionPoint> endpoints,
      TextSelectionDelegate delegate,
      ClipboardStatusNotifier? clipboardStatus,
      Offset? lastSecondaryTapDownPosition,
      ) {
    //.. some code here

    return MapSelectionToolbar(
      anchorAbove: anchorAbove,
      anchorBelow: anchorBelow,
      clipboardStatus: clipboardStatus,
      handleCopy: canCopy(delegate)
          ? () => handleCopy(delegate, clipboardStatus)
          : null,
      handleMap: selectedText.isNotEmpty
          ? () {
        openLink(generateLocationLinkFromQuery(selectedText));
        delegate.hideToolbar();
      }
          : null,
      handleCut: canCut(delegate) ? () => handleCut(delegate) : null,
      handlePaste: canPaste(delegate) ? () => handlePaste(delegate) : null,
      handleSelectAll:
      canSelectAll(delegate) ? () => handleSelectAll(delegate) : null,
    );
  }
}

class MapSelectionToolbar extends StatefulWidget { ....

SelectableRegion(
        selectionControls: MapTextSelectionControls(),
        focusNode: _selectableRegionFocusNode, ....)
```

[image]

However Flutter is warning that the way I have it implemented right now is about to be deprecated but I could not figure out or find sufficient resources on how the new way of achieving the same result would be.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter 3.7 has a new way to implement context menus.
Here are the details and examples: [A new way to customize context menus](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/context-menus)
You can do something like this:

```
SelectableText(
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
    final TextEditingValue value = editableTextState.textEditingValue;
    final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> buttonItems = editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems;
    buttonItems.insert(
      0,
      ContextMenuButtonItem(
        label: 'Send email',
        onPressed: () {
          // your "send email" code    
        },
      ),
    );
    return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
      anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
      buttonItems: buttonItems,
    );
  },
)
```

Another example with SelectionArea and editable text spans:

```
SelectionArea(
        onSelectionChanged: (value) {
          selectedText = value?.plainText ?? "";
        },
        contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
          final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> buttonItems = editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems;
          buttonItems.insert(
            0,
            ContextMenuButtonItem(
              label: 'Send email',
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint("send \"$selectedText\" by email");
                // your "send email" code
              },
            ),
          );
          return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
            anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
            buttonItems: buttonItems,
          );
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
          body: const Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ',
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Text.rich(
                  TextSpan(
                    text: "consetetur sadipscing elitr",
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: I don't user SelectableText, instead I have text spans wrapped inside a SelectableRegion widget which requires selectionControls in addition to contextMenuBuilder. I did put in the code you provided into contextMenuBuilder but it had no effect. Can you comment on this?

Comment: I've added another example. Does this solve the issue?

Comment: Your second example is text wrapped in a SelectionArea with no reference to contextMenuBuilder. My question is how to add contextMenuBuilder to SelectableRegion because right now if I paste the contextMenuBuilder code you provided in the first example into SelectionArea nothing changes.

Comment: At the moment there seems to be no solution for the SelectableRegion. But maybe the SelectionArea can help out? (I edited my second example.)

Comment: Yes thank you it worked, but I have been unable to figure out how to extract the selected text inside onPressed (// your "send email" code). Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I have now added the "get the text" part. There must be an additional variable "selectedText" outside SelectionArea.

Comment: How to programmatically set selection all in SelectionArea?

Comment: `editableTextState.selectAll();` programmatically set selection all in SelectionArea

Answer (score 1):

These are just warnings from Flutter, nonetheless these changes happened for a reason, and the package/plugin/library requests you to replace the parameter names with the new ones. Considering there are no type changes of the parameters, you'll only need to replace the names of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

if you need a *copy* and *select all* buttons, just use:

```
contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
  return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
    anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
    buttonItems: <ContextMenuButtonItem>[
      ContextMenuButtonItem(
        onPressed: () {
          editableTextState.copySelection(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar);
        },
        type: ContextMenuButtonType.copy,
      ),
      ContextMenuButtonItem(
        onPressed: () {
          editableTextState.selectAll(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar);
        },
        type: ContextMenuButtonType.selectAll,
      ),
    ],
  );
},
```

You can add more buttons like *cut* just by changing the `copySelection` to `cutSelection` and changing the `ContextMenuButtonType`.

Similar for *paste* (`pasteText`) and others...

Source: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/context-menus